# Heroku with PgAdmin: How can I add new Maintenance DB using pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pgadmin, heroku-postgres

I can't add a new maintenance db in pgadmin:

[image]

It only shows postgres, template1, and edb.

I want to add a new one. How can I do it?

I mean to say that I can not able to connect Heroku db as I am not able to give maintenance db here.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is your friend.

Comment: You can find a possible answer here: [What is the Maintenance DB asked by pgAdmin?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68077/what-is-the-maintenance-db-asked-by-pgadmin).